# Disable drag / drop of folders

Tags: fine-uploader

Is it possible to completely disable drag and drop of folders in Fineuploader? I would prefer to just set some configuration option like

```
{
    allowFolderDD : false
}
```

Than have to start intercepting the `dragover` event myself for example.

Comment: Just folders? Do you still want multiple files?

Comment: yes we want multiple files still. Chrome users have complained that dragging folders is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that only Chrome (at the moment of this post) supports folder drop.

Second, Fine Uploader does not have a way of setting a configuration to enable only files and not folders to be uploaded. Please, open a feature request if you would benefit from configuring files only drop (in Chrome only, of course).